# Which one to choose: subject-wise or record-wise

Tags: classification, accuracy, train-test-split

I want to do some classifications on open access ["Activity Recognition Using Wearable Physiological Measurements"](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Activity+recognition+using+wearable+physiological+measurements) data set. In this dataset, there are 40 subjects whose Electrocardiogram (ECG), Thoracic Electrical Bioimpedance (TEB), and Electrodermal Activity (EDA) information have been recorded for activity recognition. For each subject, there are 28 row samples for each activity.

I want to do classification using a Decision Tree, Random Forest, XGBoost, and SVM. So I tried to split the data into the test and the train data to measure the accuracy of the models. But I'm unsure whether I should split by subjects or just by the records.
Would you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Both are valid and measure different things. Holding out records answers the question "Given some data about people, how well can we recognize their future actions"? Holding out subjects answers the question "How well can we recognize actions from new people?". The second is harder. But the first can be valid if you intend to have a "calibration" step of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. @JohnMadden